# Call event from another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I have 2 pages : PageListAnimals and PageEditAnimal.

In PageListAnimals, there is a gridview with animals information. I can click on each animal to open the PageEditAnimal : that opens another page, in a new window.

When i finished editing animal information, i would like to save and close the window PageEditAnimal, and after that, the other window PageListAnimals will be refreshed, or the grid view inside updated.

I know solutions exist in javascript, but i would like to implement it server-side.

I think it's possible to have something like Observer pattern for example. When the PageEditAnimal is closed, that notifies the PageListAnimals to update himself.

Please give me a clue or something to help to solve that problem.

**EDIT - RESOLVED :**

The solution was to call the refresh of the parent from the child, but i just managed to do this in javascript :

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      window.opener.refresh();
 }
```

Then in the parent, the javascript function method() has to update the gridview inside.

Comment: Ajax is the best way to handle this.  Another solution is to refresh the browser in javascript on the close event of the popup window.  Because the event takes place client side, you have to initiate it client side.

Comment: You can also force the parent to refresh from within the child, but again.  Javascript.

Comment: Is there your project is "Web Application" or "Website"???

Comment: It's a web application !

Comment: Then some how it's possible but you have to use javascript function to close window and call this function in code behind using "registerstartupscript". Is it fine?

Comment: My problem is not to close the window. This could be done by a user click. What i would like, its after that : when i close this window, the grid view in the other windows is refreshed.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to open another page do do the edit?

Instead open in the same page, and after the edit is done, redirect to the *PageListAnimals* page.

```
Response.Redirect("PageListAnimals.aspx");
```

If you insist to keep the *PageListAnimals* open, then I think the only way to do it is with javascript.  Just create a call to a server side function that contains `GridView.Databind()` method.

Comment: It's like this and i can't change it. The PageEditAnimal has to be a new window

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

add this script in the head of your page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(window).focus(function () {
        document.getElementById('<%= Button3.ClientID %>').click();
    });
</script>
```

Add this button, to call the code behind that should update the GridView

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" style="display:none"; runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button3_Click" />
```

And code behind  should look like this:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This is how your data should be bind in GridView
    GridView1.DataBind(); //GridView1 -> name whatever your gridview is named
}
```

**Caution**
This code is called whenever you go to the page `PageListAnimals`, so use it with careful.

Comment: This code is called when the PageListAnimals is focused. I just want her to be updated when the other window PageEditAnimal is closed :/

Comment: Yes, but you can only see the data if you go to that page, and if you do so, the page will have new data. You are not interested to refresh data if you don't watch them.